# Basics of LINQ :: VB.NET specific Articles / Tutorials

Tags: vb.net

I want to learn usage of LINQ in vb.net.  I have no idea at all where to start.
Could anybody kindly advise me some good articles/tutorials to begin with?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best LINQ Tutorial?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179217/best-linq-tutorial)

Comment: Take a look at [101 LINQ Samples - *in VB* ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/bb688088.aspx)

Comment: The 101 Samples worked for me too... just stare at them and stare at them and you'll get it.

Comment: @Will A This is not a duplicate, because Linq syntax is different in VB.Net than in C#. As far as I can see all the answers to the other questions are C#

Answer (score 1):

[Hooked on linq](http://www.hookedonlinq.com/) ([archived copy](https://web.archive.org/web/20140823041217/http://www.hookedonlinq.com:80/)) is a good start.

Answer (score 1):

- The MSDN [101 VB LINQ samples](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-Sample-Queries-13a42a54) are good, as Kobi commented.
- I also liked the coverage in the book [Programming VB 2008](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596518439).

Comment: You had 7 hidden links in your post, I don't know why, so I removed them.